# NodeJS, changing file location

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to move a specific file into a folder (which I create in case it doesn't exist) but for some reason I get the error all the time,

```
events.js:72 // <- this isn't even an existing file in my project :o
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/user/project/public/uploads/553283d3216c3895055612dd/06704d37f87197d5218522ecc102d932.jpg'
```

this is my code

```
var sourceFile, destFile, destFolder;

sourceFile = fs.createReadStream(file.thumbnail.path);
destFolder = __dirname + '/public/uploads/' + context.user._id;
destFile = fs.createReadStream(destFolder + '/' + file.thumbnail.name);

if (!fs.existsSync(destFolder)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(destFolder);
}

sourceFile.pipe(destFile);
```

anyone has any idea what possible is wrong here and can I fix this ?
PS: the /public/upload/ folder has 777 permission.

thanks!

Comment: That error indicates that the file doesn't exist or can't be open -- are you sure it exists?

Comment: the `dest` file isn't exist (of course it isnt as this is the code destination, im trying to move an existing one to there - as the error reference to the `dest`)

Comment: Why are you testing for the existence of the directory *after* trying to read from a file from it? Your `fs.existsSync` check should probably come before you create the stream. However, that's not the problem you're currently running into: you're trying you write to a read stream, and the file doesn't exist.

Comment: even if i'll define `destFile` after the checking (like you said) I will still have the same error as the file that it refers to isn't exist (thats why I called it `destFile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to open a file for reading that doesn't exist (the dest file -- of course it doesn't exist).  You want to open the file for writing.

```
destFile = fs.createWriteStream(destFolder + '/' + file.thumbnail.name);
```